# Auto Format Form Input Field Value On Blur

Tags: angular

I have an number input field in a form. If the user leaves the field the value should automatically append two zero digits when the user did not entered any digits.

Examples:

- User enters "1" -> The value should become 1.00.
- User enters "1.12" -> The value should not change.

How would I achieve this in angular using reactive forms?

Example code:

```
<md-input-container>
      <input mdInput type="number" placeholder="Number" formControlName="amount" step="any"/>
</md-input-container>

this.formBuilder.group({
      amount: [this._formData.amount, [Validators.required]],
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding a function that takes in the number and formats it.

```
format(amt){
    if(amt % 1 == 0){
      amt = amt + '.00';
      this.amount = amt;
    }
  }
```

Also, take in the consideration that if the user focus back on that same field, those added '.00' need to be removed. So, I added the following function when `focus` is triggered.

```
remove(amt){
    if(amt % 1 == 0){
      this.amount = amt * 1;;
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<md-input-container class="example-full-width">
    <input mdInput placeholder="Amount" type="number" [(ngModel)]="amount" formControlName="amount" (blur)="format(amount)" (focus)="remove(amount)">
  </md-input-container>
```

Plnkr [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/mrEcN7?p=preview)